# Assembly put pixel procedure doesn't work

Tags: assembly, pixel, procedure

I am trying to launch procedure put pixel in assembly in graphic mode on DOS NASM.
When I don't use procedure it work, but now it show me only one blue pixel and two letters "h" in the left corner.
My code:

```
segment .data

segment .code
..start:
mov ax, 13h 
int 10h

mov ax, 0a000h ; The offset to video memory
mov es, ax ; We load it to ES through AX, becouse immediate operation is not allowed on ES

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

mov ax, 10 ; Y coord
mov bx, 20 ; X coord
mov dl, 4
call putpixel

mov ax, 1 ; Y coord
mov bx, 2 ; X coord
mov dl, 4
call putpixel
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
putpixel: 
mov cx,320
mul cx; multiply AX by 320 (cx value)
add ax,bx ; and add X
mov di,ax
mov [es:di],dl
ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


xor ah, ah
int 16h ;keyboard

mov ax, 3
int 10h   ; go to text mode

mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h
```

I got it from tutorial, but I have any idea why it doesn't work.
What is wrong in this code? I was trying to show two pixels.
Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works properly to set the two pixels, but then falls into the `putpixel` subroutine, causing havoc.

I've rearranged your code so that it finishes properly.  Either put your subroutines last, or first, or jmp around them.  (I generally go with first, so that the main logic (start, main, whatever) is the last of the source code.  Your choice, of course)

```
    segment .data

    segment .code
..start:
    mov ax, 13h 
    int 10h               ; switch to 320x200 mode

    mov ax, 0a000h        ; The offset to video memory
    mov es, ax            ; We load it to ES through AX,
                          ; because immediate operation
                          ; is not allowed on ES

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

    mov ax, 10            ; Y coord
    mov bx, 20            ; X coord
    mov dl, 4
    call putpixel

    mov ax, 1             ; Y coord
    mov bx, 2             ; X coord
    mov dl, 4
    call putpixel

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

    xor ah, ah
    int 16h               ; keyboard (wait for key)

    mov ax, 3
    int 10h               ; go to text mode

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h               ; return to DOS, exit code 0

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

putpixel:
    push dx               ; oops, mul changes dx too
    mov cx, 320
    mul cx                ; multiply Y (ax) by 320 (one row)
    add ax, bx            ; and add X (bx) (result= dx:ax)
    mov di, ax
    pop dx
    mov [es:di], dl       ; store color/pixel
    ret

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Congratulations on tackling assembly language!  It's not always easy, but I find it amazing and fun to explore!  Good luck!

---

EDIT:

Oops!  Totally forgot that the `mul` command affects `DX`.

```
mul cx  -->  dx:ax = ax * cx  (oops!)
```

Comment: I was trying this order before, but it did't show any pixel. I have compiled this code and it did not show any pixel too.

Comment: Does the screen 'flip' to graphics mode and then back to text mode?   Perhaps the `int 16h` call doesn't wait, but returns immediately?  I don't remember the details of DOS int16h.   Try inserting a loop instead to make it stop after drawing the pixels... I'll edit answer to show what I mean.

Comment: Before it stayed in graphic mode and show nothing. After edit it is the same, but now 'esc' couldn't go to text mode(because of the loop). Firstly when I trying do it without procedure it show pixels.

Comment: Hmmmm.  Ok, so things are working as expected, you should remove the `freeze: jmp freeze` bit... and I've looked up int16h/ah=00... it does wait for a keystroke.  Yay for Ralf! http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int.htm

Comment: From what I've found, you're doing everything right!  BUT... the colors displayed are based on a palette, and the color 4 you're using may not be blue at this point.  Try changing the `4` in both putpixel calls (dl value) to something else... `55` or some random number (0-255) (00h-ffh) (A decent reference: http://webpages.charter.net/danrollins/techhelp/0113.HTM)

Comment: So I don't know what it's wrong now. I have used this tutorial: http://devdocs.inightmare.org/x86-assembly-graphics-part-i-mode-13h/ and when I put pixel without procedure it works properly. For me programm looks fine too. And I have tryed different colour.

Comment: Totally went blonde there.... the `mul` command affect `DX`... so we're losing the value (color!) of the desired pixel!  I've edited the answer again to add in the `push dx` and `pop dx` commands to retain the value of dl (the color!)

Comment: Works now!  Yes, had to recreate your setup... dos nasm... dosbox, source-code... whew!